# Salable quantity empty

Tags: magento2.3

I just recently migrated our database from Magento 1.6.1 to Magento 2.3.3 now everything seems `OK` but after testing all functionality I found out that whenever I add a product in the cart it says that the product is not available even though I know that there are quantities for this product below is how my product grid looks like

[image]

As you can see in the Salable Quantity it says `No manage stock` now when I check the actual product here is the content

[image]
[image]

As you can see the Quantity of the product is still 500 but when you look at the Salable quantity tab. There is no value.

Answer (score 0):

First, take the backup your **Database** before trying the below solution.

Run the below query on your Magento Database.

```
insert into `inventory_source_item`
    (source_code, sku, quantity, status)
    select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)))
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got an error Duplicate entry 'default-1023' for key 'INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_SKU'

Answer (score 0):

I also I also encountered salable quantity being empty on new just imported products. Reindex doesn't help.

[image]

I noticed that there is no entry for these products in the table inventory_source_item. But, if the product is saved in Admin, an entry is added to this table.

So I run next query

```
insert ignore into `inventory_source_item`(source_code, sku, quantity, status)
select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `css` join `catalog_product_entity` as `cpe` on((`css`.`product_id` = `cpe`.`entity_id`)))
```

This is to add missing data in the inventory_source_item table. "IGNORE" will skip duplicate values.